# Qpid Proton Python: not reconnecting after long job

Tags: python, amqp, qpid

I'm using Qpid Proton Python for an AMQP consumer that runs jobs which can last for +1 minute.

After the job is done, I'm getting a `connection_closed` with `Condition('amqp:resource-limit-exceeded', 'local-idle-timeout expired')`.

I understand this happens because my blocking job is preventing the heartbeat.

The thing that puzzles me is why I'm not getting reconnected. Debugging proton, I get to [this line of code](https://github.com/apache/qpid-proton/blob/master/python/proton/_reactor.py#L969), where `self.connection.state` has a value of **36**, so `self.connection.state & Endpoint.LOCAL_ACTIVE` returns 0.

1. Why is that? Can I do something to enable reconnection?
2. Is there anything I can do client-side to avoid disconnection in the first place?

here's a working code to reproduce the scenario:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from time import sleep

from proton.handlers import MessagingHandler
from proton.reactor import Container


class ExampleConsumer(MessagingHandler):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        super().__init__(2, False)
        self.queue = queue

    def on_start(self, event):
        self.container = event.container
        self.conn = event.container.connect(url='localhost:5672')
        self.receiver = event.container.create_receiver(self.conn, self.queue)
        print('listening for new messages on /' + self.queue)

    def on_message(self, event):
        print('sleeping 60')
        sleep(60)
        print('done sleeping')
        self.accept(event.delivery)

    def on_connection_error(self, event):
        print('connection_error', event.connection.condition, event.connection.remote_condition)


try:
    Container(ExampleConsumer('examples')).run()
except KeyboardInterrupt: pass
```

Comment: Would it be possible to see a [example] for this?

Comment: @Trilarion there's an MRE. It needs a working AMQP broker at `localhost:5672` and a message on `examples` queue. You can use examples at qpid source code for that.

Comment: Here's a repo with a complete MRE ready to reproduce: https://github.com/martintuk/qpid-python-mre

Comment: @Tuk did you manage to solve this?